# Error metodo nombre no encontrado

Tags: python

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\data\listener.py", line 94, in 
>       back_dir(os.getcwd()) NameError: name 'back_dir' is not defined

Clase que estoy utilizando:

```
class back():
    def back_dir(self,current_path):
                    c=current_path.split('\\')
                    new_path=''
                    i=0
                    while i<len(c)-1:
                            if i!=0:
                                    new_path=new_path+"\\"+c[i]
                            else:
                                    new_path=c[i]
                            i+=1
                    os.chdir(new_path)
```

Parte del codigo donde recibo el error:

```
back_dir(os.getcwd())
```

Sin embargo deberia funcionar? Me pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios errores en tu código. En la definición de la clase no haría falta usar paréntesis a no ser que esté heredando de otra. Por convención, las clases se definen usando CamelCase,...

Cuando instancias la clase puedes acceder a sus métodos. Por ejemplo:

```
b = back()
b.back_dir(os.getcwd())
```